A multiverse of afterworlds
My question touches on multiverse theory and possible worlds. Put simply, could there be an infinite number of afterworlds, I’m most fixated on there being an infinite number of possible hells. Each one different in their own way. One that I’ve been obsessing over is having root canal, hitting a nerve, and this process looping infinitely. I should probably see a shrink but I just can’t shake the possibility that this is my fate. I think Leibniz said that possibility demands existence, or something along those lines. So this is an extension of the principle of plentitude I believe it is called.
I’m not specifically thinking about Christianity or any religion. Just an afterworld that transcends all religions. The ultimate god or devil (it’s impossible to believe that everything is in control by an evil entity because there is good in the world, if an evil deity was in control then there would be no good, and there is good in my life and I’m certain of that fact), whoever is in control of the afterlife - this could be a deist god that doesn’t intervene and is in charge of who goes to hell or heaven . But even if you’re a good person you may still be sent to hell. This would make god evil of course. But since it’s possible why can’t it happen? Maybe there’s some arbitrary process when we die where good people are sent to hell. Or maybe I’m the only person in hell for eternity. This is all possible so why shouldn’t it happen? Just because something could possibly happen does not necessitate its actuality.
This has actually become an obsession and really troubling me as there is no fact of the matter, and nobody can prove this type of afterworld actually will exist or not.
So I’m wondering if any philosophers have dealt with this specific topic: whether there is an infinitude of possible or actual afterworlds, and whether there could be a god that could be evil and your soul is destined to hell for eternity even though you’ve been a good person. This is hard to reconcile with the fact that there is good in the world, so how could god be evil. I’d say maybe the part of him that determines who goes to hell is evil, sort of in isolation to his other characteristics or properties. It’s all a bit absurd.
I’m currently agnostic about these problems and it’s not reasonable to believe such a fate will be mine (but based on what foundation and what evidence or lack of evidence telling me it’s still possible), but my gut seems to be telling me that I’m destined to the tooth drilling torture for eternity. Maybe philosophy isn’t the best way to deal with these problems, maybe psychology would be. I dunno.

Do you think that one single Hell is not enough?

I believe that the worst possible hell could exist. Maybe some hells aren’t as bad for the individual than others. But I guess that hell is by common definition the worst possible existence. Some say that’s an absence of God’s love, others may say that it’s being infinitely burned for eternity or having root canal with no anaesthesia for eternity. These are all different possible afterworlds, and what you most dread is what it’s like. But the question is how does the soul split off into all these different hells?
Maybe there’s only one hell, however, one which actualises your worst fears.

@MauroALLEGRANZA

"It is not possible that I go to root canal hell for no reason" necessarily follows from the assumptions in your second paragraph.

even if you’re a good person you may still be sent to hell. This would make god evil


If I go to root canal hell for no reason, God is evil


if an evil deity was in control then there would be no good


If God is evil there exists no good.


there is good in my life and I’m certain of that fact


There exists good.

Apply  modus tollens.

2 and 3 therefore: God is not evil.

Apply modus tollens again.

4 and 1 therefore: It is not possible that I go to root canal hell for no reason.


Some similarity here to Alvin Plantinga’s ontological argument from possible worlds, which you can read about on SEP in section 8.

Thank you I’ve thought along similar lines and I hope I have not misunderstood. However what if God allows good in our universe but when it comes to the afterlife he is inconsistent and sends good people to hell. Isn’t that a possibility? I mean if he’s not wholly good (since there is evil in the world which he allows?)? And the evil part will send good people to hell. It’s not necessary that god is omnibenevolent?
